# Inserting geometry (JSON) into loopbackjs model

Tags: node.js, postgresql, postgis, loopbackjs

I am adding and editing geometry in loopback with the angular SDK into PostGIS, and I have the following working fine:

```
ProjectGeoms.upsert({"id":"129","projectGeom":   {"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[arrays of x/y co-ordinates]],"crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"EPSG:4326"}}}}, successCallback, errorCallback)
```

The SQL query being run is:

```
loopback:connector:postgresql SQL: UPDATE "public"."project_geom" SET  "ref"=$1,"project_geom"=$2
Parameters: 129,{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[arrays of x/y co-ordinates]],"crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"EPSG:4326"}}} +2ms
```

This is for a geometry that already exists. However, when I add it for a geometry which doesn't exist (the same JSON structure, but with an id 124), then it does not work.

The SQL query being run is:

```
loopback:connector:postgresql SQL: INSERT INTO "public"."project_geom" ("ref","project_geom") SELECT $1,$2 RETURNING 
Parameters: 124,{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[arrays of x/y co-ordinates]],"crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"EPSG:4326"}}} +2ms
```

The full error message is below:

```
loopback:connector:postgresql error: syntax error at end of input
at Connection.parseE (C:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.4.30-   0\apache2\htdocs\project\api\node_modules\loopback-connector-postgresql\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:534:11)
at Connection.parseMessage (C:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.4.30-0\apache2\htdocs\project\api\node_modules\loopback-connector-postgresql\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:361:17)
at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.4.30-0\apache2\htdocs\project\api\node_modules\loopback-connector-postgresql\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:105:22)
at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:765:14)
at Socket.emit (events.js:92:17)
at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:427:10)
at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:423:5)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:166:9)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:128:10) +15ms
```

If I run the following query in Postgres directly:

```
INSERT INTO project_geom (ref,project_geom) VALUES (124,'{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[arrays of x/y co-ordinates]],"crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"EPSG:4326"}}}'::json);
```

I am able to insert the value without issue.

The table data schema is `(ref::integer, project_geom::json)`

Comment: The Insert query can't just end like that. `RETURNING` should be followed by a list columns, expressions to return.

Comment: Thanks Jakub - you put me on the right track - feel free to submit an answer

Comment: I think it will be much better if you answer this question yourself as you actually know what happened and it will help others.

Comment: ok, or we could both answer!

Comment: You earned it, I just gave you a hint.

Comment: Doesn't PostGIS require GeoJSON values written to the database to be wrapped in calls to [`ST_GeomFromGeoJSON()`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromGeoJSON.html)?  Is that something you're doing (and if so, how)?

Comment: Yes, that's in a separate function: `IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
        INSERT INTO project_sites (geom,ref)
     VALUES(ST_Multi(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(NEW.project_geom::text)),NEW.ref);
        RETURN NEW;` This is an editable view by the way..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Case of RTFM - I missed this page http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Model+definition+JSON+file#ModeldefinitionJSONfile-IDproperties, which clearly states that

`LoopBack CRUD methods expect the model to have an "id" property if the model is backed by a database.`

Duh.  My model didn't have one. Looking at the [code](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-postgresql/blob/17429fabe20eb141bef4d9adec5fb672b7fa95a7/lib/postgresql.js#L275) of the loopback-postgresql-connector, it needs ***the*** ID field to return an id with the "RETURNING" clause. Although this is documented by loopback, the problem in this particular case could be made clearer in my view, so I intend to submit a patch to change the verbose log/error messages.